# Ionic 3 and AngularFire2 signOut()

Tags: cordova, firebase, angularfire2, ionic3

I am getting error when I try to signout from my ionic3 app using email authentication with firebase.

I followed the signout  method in the docs

```
signOut() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage)
}
```

however I get `cannot read property email of null`

what am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE:

I have this code in my LoginPage **login.ts**

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
        if (data.email) {
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Where are you using `email`? Are you sure the error is not in a different part of your code?

Comment: I have a code in my login.ts.. I updated the post..

Comment: seems like `data` is null.. did you try logging error in subscribe?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not an expert but I think it's safe to check if data is null or not before accessing data.email. As in,

```
   ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
        if (data && data.email) {
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
        }
    })
}
```